# How to merge new traineddata into eng.traineddata on Tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I need to train a new font of English. At the end of training, I have file font.traineddata. How can I merge this into the existing eng.traineddata?

I know that I can use the new traineddata by invoking command
tesseract input output -l eng+font

But is it possible to merge 2 traineddata?

Answer (score 0):

As read on google and google Tesseract-OCR group, it is not possible to merge two traineddata files and you need to train the better one to work like the other one also. 
Please refer to this link also : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tesseract-ocr/MSYezIbckvs/kO1VoNKMDMQJ